# SQL Server 2012 change query result position

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-server-2012

Traditionally in SQL Server while executing a query the result is displayed below the query dividing the screen horizontally.

**Is there any settings that can be done to displays the result to the side (splitting vertically)?**

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: No.But you can do tools-->option-->display results in separate tab.

Comment: @DudiKonfino I am not able to find tools-->option--> **display** can you explain me under which category to find this **Display**

Comment: tools-->option-->query results-->results to grid-->display results in separate tab.